# How do i fix uneveness of RoundRectangle2d?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a this piece of code to add a rounded JProgressBar to a JPanel:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

public class RoundedProgressBar extends JProgressBar {
    public RoundedProgressBar() {
        setOpaque(false); // Make the progress bar transparent
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0)); // Add padding
        setUI(new RoundedProgressBarUI());
    }

    private class RoundedProgressBarUI extends BasicProgressBarUI {
        @Override
        protected void paintDeterminate(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
            int arcWidth = 10;
            int arcHeight = 10;

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            Insets b = progressBar.getInsets(); // Border insets
            int barRectWidth = progressBar.getWidth() - b.right - b.left;
            int barRectHeight = progressBar.getHeight() - b.top - b.bottom;

            // Fill the progress bar background with the background color
            g2.setColor(progressBar.getBackground());
            Shape shapeBg = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, barRectWidth, barRectHeight, arcWidth, arcHeight);
            g2.fill(shapeBg);

            // Fill the progress bar with the progress color
            int amountFull = getAmountFull(b, barRectWidth, barRectHeight);
            g2.setColor(progressBar.getForeground());
            Shape shape = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, amountFull, barRectHeight, arcWidth, arcHeight);
            g2.fill(shape);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the image below it looks ok, but I can clearly see that the right side of the RoundRecangle is different from the left side. Any tips on how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: I think it would help to turn antialiasing on.

Answer (score 0):

Using antialiasing can help smoothen out the edges for you, and you should get something looking like this ->

[image]

Here's what you need to do ->

```
...
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
Insets b = progressBar.getInsets(); // Border insets
int barRectWidth = progressBar.getWidth() - b.right - b.left;
int barRectHeight = progressBar.getHeight() - b.top - b.bottom;
            
RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2.setRenderingHints(hints);

g2.setColor(progressBar.getBackground());
Shape shapeBg = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, barRectWidth, barRectHeight, arcWidth, arcHeight);
g2.fill(shapeBg);
...
```

For more details check out [Controlling Rendering Quality](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html)